# Javascript - loading to array possible infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I was trying to load some content to my array through a cycle but it appears the browser tab crashes but I can't identify the reason why.

Here's my load function,

```
var postArray = "";
var postsCounter = 0;
var post = [];
postArray = [];

LoadPosts: function(){
    //Load user posts
    var tempPosts = localStorage.getItem('posts');
    if(tempPosts){
        postArray = JSON.parse(tempPosts);
    }
    postsCounter = postArray.length;

    //Load items posts
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        post = {
            id: postsCounter,
            title: items[i].title,
            points: items[i].points,
            comments: items[i].comments,
            src: items[i].src,
            type: items[i].type,
            user: undefined
        };
        postArray.push(post);
        postsCounter++;
    }
    PostManager.Exec();
},
```

And my items,

```
var items =
[
    {
        "title":"It's Not Like I'm That Ugly",
        "points": 550,
        "comments": 67,
        "src": "/assets/images/someimage.jpg",
        "type": "funny"
    }
    //It goes on
];
```

Comment: You have defined var post = [] which is an array but inside for loop you are trying to create an object post = {..}

Comment: What is this supposed to mean: `LoadPosts: function(){` and the `},` at the end of script? Are you trying to label the function? This is not part of an object literal, because I see `var post = [];` etc before it.

Comment: You can add a console.log(item) inside the loop to see how much times it gets executed through the browser console.

Comment: I think that you code works well, you have a sintaxis error '},' at end.

Comment: No I don't, the class goes on I just didn't see the point of adding all of it

Answer (score -1):

I figured the problem out, it appears I was declaring the items variable incorrectly.
It should be like this,

```
var items =
[
    {
        myTitle:"It's Not Like I'm That Ugly",
        myPoints: 550,
        myComments: 67,
        mySrc: "/assets/images/someimage.jpg",
        myType: "funny"
    },
    //It goes on
];
```